# Google Sheets - three way lookup with vertical and horizontal criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dp15wVvTn-qZ_oBbnFblQZSlC8FrJ3qWvTgs80R5Ig8/edit?usp=sharing

I need to do a vlookup across 3 criteria - one is a vertical criteria and two are horizontal criteria. I've been googling to find a solution but I can't find something that works with data that's shaped like this.

This is raw data format:
[image]
As you can see, cities are defined on the vertical axis whereas product categories & sub categories are defined on the horizontal axis.

This is the expected output:

[image]

Essentially, the data needs to formatted in a way that it can be fed into a visualization tool.

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know of a way to achieve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
={"City","Category","Sub-Category","Search Volime"; 
 INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(B4:J="",,A4:A&"×"&B2:J2&"×"&B3:J3&"×"&B4:J)), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that formula is something else, I thought I was good at using spreadsheets but you're amazing!